# Missing Files XCODE Project Derived Data

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, missing-data

Somehow/Someway, my .app, my.xctest and everything in my Products folder are suddenly gone.  However I have found these files in my derived data directory by going to XCODE-Preferences-Locations- and clicking that little right arrow.  Now I need to add these files back to my project, but I cannot figure out how, any ideas?

Also for some reason my Provisioning Profiles arent recognized anymore.  I have confirmed through keychain, my apple developers account, and build settings that everything is correct.  Xcode automatically says it wants to fix it for me.  However, it only results in them not being found.  I have no idea how this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the answer to this, as the files which were once there, just disappeared.  I ended up deleting all my Provisioning Profiles, Saving my Xcode file to dropbox, uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling.  Once Xcode re-installed, I created a new Development Cert and Provisioning Profile.  Once that was done, I reinstalled my pod file, and reopened my XC file.  Once the project opened I set my new certificates and everything but my XCTest file was present.  My project now works smoothly.  :)

Comment: Seems like a valid solution! Uninstalling Xcode solved all my problems.